# Extract TCP payload from pcap file

Tags: http, tcp, scapy, pcap, tcpdump

Using `tcpdump`, I am capturing network traffic. I am interested in extracting the actual TCP payload data, i.e. HTTP traffic in my particular case.

I tried to achieve that using `scapy`, but I only found function `remove_payload()`. Is there a corresponding counterpart? Or do you know of any other tools that provide such functionality?

Unfortunately, I did not find a satisfactory scapy documentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case other users might have similar questions: I ended up using the following script:

```
infile=infile.pcap
outfile=outfile
ext=txt

rm -f ${outfile}_all.${ext}

for stream in $(tshark -nlr $infile -Y tcp.flags.syn==1 -T fields -e tcp.stream | sort -n | uniq | sed 's/\r//')
do
    echo "Processing stream $stream: ${outfile}_${stream}.${ext}"
    tshark -nlr $infile -qz "follow,tcp,raw,$stream" | tail -n +7 | sed 's/^\s\+//g' | xxd -r -p | tee ${outfile}_${stream}.${ext} >> ${outfile}_all.${ext}
done
```

Comment: I looked way too much in the internet to find this ...

Comment: @Florian How can we process it as packets using python scapy. I am trying to process it without stream but getting some out-of-order packets.

Answer (score 8):

You can read a pcap with Scapy easily with `rdpcap`, you can then use the `Raw` (right above TCP) layer of your packets to play with HTTP content:

```
from scapy.all import *

pcap = rdpcap("my_file.pcap")

for pkt in pcap:
    if Raw in pkt:
        print pkt[Raw]
```

Comment: Any suggestions how I can write those bytes to a file rather then to the console? Also, I would not want to output additional newlines.

Comment: Python `open()` and `write()` deals with I/O. Python's `print` function append a line feed, so if you do not use it and rather write the bytes to a file, it should not be there anymore.

Comment: I should have been more clear: `write` does not allow the call `f.write(pkt[Raw])` (TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not Raw). I could not find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Found it: `out = open("out.txt", "wb")` and `out.write(pkt[Raw].load)`. While Scapy seems to be really powerful, it's a shame that there is essentially no documentation.

Comment: There is some [here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/scapydoc.pdf), [here](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/) and a short tutorial [here](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/blob/master/doc/notebooks/Scapy%20in%2015%20minutes.ipynb) but yes, there is a lack of documentation.

Comment: This answer only works if packets are delivered in sequence and have no missing sequence numbers.  The point of using TCP is for handling exceptions to those situations (which are common in the real world).